# mkdir()/chmod() TOCTOU race condition under gcc linux

Tags: c, linux, sonarqube, race-condition

I have gcc 'C' code running in RHEL 8.x / 9.x that has been flagged as having a 'TOCTOU race condition'.

It does a mkdir() followed by a chmod() and SonarQube points at the chmod().

I assume it is complaining that someone could do bad things between the mkdir() and the chmod() resulting in a substituted file or symlink getting 'chmod()'ed instead of the new directory I created.

The reason I do the subsequent chmod() is because the umask value will alter the permissions I specified on the mkdir(), so the chmod() is there to 'fix up' the file permissions to what I originally asked for.

Since my code is part of a larger system and is called by various programs as an entry in a  shared object, I don't have the ability to modify umask as it would alter the umask for the whole process and any other thread that might be running at the same time could have its file creation behavior altered. (I don't have control over any other threads that may be running from the same process, or the umask that was used to start a given process).

I am under the impression that I can't create a directory with open() (which would have allowed me to use fchmod() on the opened handle and presumably avoid the race condition).

Is there some 'standard' way to avoid this TOCTOU race?

The 'create sub-directory' code is really only called if an attempt to create a file in said sub-directory fails with an 'ENOENT' (assuming that the failure reason is that the sub-directory doesn't exist).

(I'm trying to create this sub-directory in a '/tmp' type directory that gets erased on every system re-boot. The files I want to create will go in my new sub-directory, and the sub-directory is expected to need creation the first time my code is called after a reboot).

Something like the simplified:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int create_subdir(char *temp_dir_path);

   int create_subdir(char *temp_dir_path)

   {  /* create_subdir */

   int rc;                         /* Return code                                                          */

      rc = 0;

      /***************************************************************/
      /* Does the temp directory already exist within the parent     */
      /* directory? Try to create it to find out                     */
      /***************************************************************/

      rc = mkdir(temp_dir_path, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO );

      if (rc == 0)
      {  /***************************************************************/
         /* We created it.                                              */
         /* Try and fix up any missing mode bits the umask may have     */
         /* prevented from getting set.                                 */
         /***************************************************************/

         rc = chmod(temp_dir_path, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO);

      }

      return(rc);

   } /* create_subdir */


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
/**************************************************************/
/*                                                            */
/*    test mainline                                           */
/*                                                            */
/**************************************************************/

{ /* Main */

char temp_dir_path[128];
char f_name[128];

int fd, rc;

   strcpy(temp_dir_path, "/tmp/new-dir");
   strcpy(f_name, "/tmp/new-dir/xyzzy");

   fd = open( f_name,
              O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC,
              S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);

   if (fd == -1)
   {
      if (errno == ENOENT)
      {  /***************************************************************/
         /* Presume this is because the sub-directory under /tmp        */
         /* doesn't yet exist. Try to create it.                        */
         /***************************************************************/

         rc = create_subdir(temp_dir_path);
      }
   }

} /* main */
```

Edit: Added a 'fuller' simplified 'C' version.

Based on the comments so far, I'll give doing mkdir() with '0' permissions while ensuring the 'parent' directory has the sticky bit enabled a try. (The parent directory already had the sticky bit set in my case).

Comment: First, using fully-qualified paths increases your exposure to TOCTOU issues, because a directory entry can be replaced between operations. The `*at` syscalls are the modern/ideal way to avoid this by operating relative to a handle you already have, but you can get something similar with `chdir()` if your process is simple enough that it doesn't have other things going on where changing directories will cause problems.

Comment: (I notice that your question doesn't currently even show us the code with the mkdir+chmod where the issue lives! We expect a [mre] -- code that we, or at least in this case the subset of us with sonarqube, can use to cause the same problem ourselves and test our answers; that means no `...` redactions -- the code should be the shortest possible thing that's complete enough to compile and test).

Comment: (_Is_ RHEL 8 modern enough to have `openat`, `mkdirat` and `fchmodat`? If so, **use them**).

Comment: (aside: I'd argue that this isn't a gcc question at all -- it's not gcc doing the analysis but sonarqube)

Comment: BTW, using the file-descriptor-addressed calls is exactly what sonarqube recommends doing; from https://www.sonarsource.com/blog/winning-the-race-against-toctou-vulnerabilities/: *If even back-to-back commands are still vulnerable, what's a poor programmer to do? Well, the first choice is using an atomic operation if one is available. When it's not, grab a file descriptor in the check - it will be mapped to the file itself - and use it instead of the file name in subsequent operations. That way, your target file can't be swapped out from under you.*

Comment: Just don't do `chmod`. The umask only removes permissions, typically those that you don't need anyway. If somebody sets their umask to something unreasonable, that's their problem, not yours.

Comment: The umask does remove permissions I need. As an entry in a .so that can be called at any time I'm not allowed to modify the process resources like current directory as it could affect other unrelated threads. As I alluded to in my post, I was under the impression that open() (and I assume openat()) can create files but not directories (and the directory is needed to create the file ultimately). So I would still end up needing to do a mkdir() followed by something to accomplish the chmod().

Comment: "The umask does remove permissions I need" Which are those, specifically?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you need to override the umask value?  You could check whether the value will interfere with your required mode and not set the mode again if the umask value won't interfere.

Assuming that you must set the mode, you can use the `open()` function to open the directory that will hold the new directory, either with `O_SEARCH` or `O_RDONLY`.  You can then use `mkdirat()` with that file descriptor as the “at” argument and a simple name (no slashes) for the directory name.

Consider whether it is safe to set `mode_t old = umask(); …create directory…; umask(old);` to set the permissions accurately without needing to use `chmod()`.  In a multithreaded application, that may not be a good choice; the `umask` value is global state, like the current directory is global state.

Otherwise, create the directory with 0 for the mode and then `chmod()` it.  You might even need to use `openat()` to open the new directory and `fchmod()` to set the mode.

Remember to close all the opened file descriptors.

Answer (score 1):

> The reason I do the subsequent chmod() is because the umask value will alter the permissions I specified on the mkdir(), so the chmod() is there to 'fix up' the file permissions to what I originally asked for.

If you use `0000` as the permission argument to `mkdir`, then the new directory will be *completely inaccessible to everyone* (except possibly root, but root is trusted anyway) in between its creation and when the `chmod` happens, so you don't need to worry about anyone taking advantage of incorrect permissions *on the newly created directory*.

As far as I know, here is no system call (not even in the `*at` family) that creates a directory and returns you an open `O_PATH`/`O_SEARCH` fd for that directory.  Therefore, there *is* still a race if you use `0000`: someone could swoop in and modify the *parent* directory in between the `mkdir` and the `chmod`, causing you to `chmod` the wrong thing.  I don't think there is any way to avoid this race.  There are, however, two workarounds that *should* be airtight:

- If it's possible to make the parent directory be owned and writable only by `root`, then have `root` create the directory you need and `chown` it to the appropriate user.
- If the parent directory must be world-writable, then make sure it is also "sticky" (mode 1777); then a process running as some other user cannot rename or delete your directory. However, a process running as some other user could *create* your directory *before* you get around to doing it; you can mitigate this by checking the ownership on "your" directory using `stat` or `fstat`.

Comment: As it turns out the parent directory (that I want to create the sub-directory within) does indeed have the sticky bit set, and seems to be owned by root. But, it is not solely writable by root (and I may or may not be root when I go to create the sub-directory). The parent directory has the same permissions as /tmp on this system. ( /tmp
drwxrwxrwt. 11 root root 4096 Mar 11 10:23 /tmp ). So if I initially create with 0000 permissions is that adequate such that this is not really vulnerable (except for the same user as the create was done for)?

Comment: As it turns out, I didn't run SonarQube myself, someone did it for my area (So I currently have limited ability to see if I 'fixed' the issue). But if it turns out the last suggestion might not be adequate, the other thing I was debating is if I were to do a mkdir(), open() the directory by name, verify that it is a directory and not a file or symlink (with fstat(), etc.), and then fchmod() the open handle that was opene()ed. But I wasn't sure if that would be considered adequate or not.

Comment: Yeah, if the parent directory is sticky, mode 1777, and owned by root, that's my second workaround.  Please note the additional caveat I just added.  mkdir+open+fchmod has the same race as mkdir+chmod.